# Weird cout behavior in C++

Tags: c++, cout, undefined-behavior

I am getting some weird behavior when using `cout` in my programm, which is similar to the following:

```
...
char *input = realpath(argv[1], NULL);
char *output = argv[2];

char *tarout = new char[strlen(output)+6];
strcpy(tarout, output);
strcat(tarout, ".temp");

cout << "Tarout: " << tarout << endl;

int tRet = tarball(input, tarout);
if(tRet != 1) {
    cerr << "Error: Could not compress directory!\nHalting package creation!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int gRet = gzip(tarout, output);
if(gRet != 1) {
    cerr << "Error: Could not compress directory!\nHalting package creation!" << endl;
    return 0;
} else {
    cout << "TAROUT: " << tarout << endl;
    if((remove(tarout))!=0) {
        cerr << "Warning: Could not delete temporary file!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
...
```

Basically this program creates a tar file and then compresses it with gzip, this is not the 100% actual code so it may not give the same odd behavior as have I been receiving.

If I removed the first `cout << "TAROUT: " << tarout << endl;` the second `cout << "TAROUT: " << tarout << endl;` would return nothing and the temporary file would not get removed, why is that?

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: Because I need to use chars for the "libtar" and "zlib" libraries and std::string does not return char* natively. It is also just a huge waste to convert from char* to string, and then back to char*.

Comment: std::string has the c_str() method.

Comment: c_str() returns const char* not char*

Comment: @Meta: You can add `'\0'` to the string, then take the address of the first element: `std::string tarout = output; tarOut += '\0'; tarball(..., &tarout[0]);`. Even then, it just looks like the API for `tarball` and `gzip` (just a quick browse online; these are horribly documented) is merely poorly designed, and that the functions should have and could work correctly if the parameters were changed to `const char*`. If that's the case, just do `const_cast<char*>(tarout.c_str())`. If none of those, use `std::vector<char>`. The point is that you never use `delete` in your code, or it's wrong.

Comment: shared_array<char> would be preferable in this instance, using a vector severely damaged readability. string is more okay, but still, if you're using a C library it's better to stay consistent and use as close to C as possible. I don't see anything in the code that would cause the behavior you described, so it's probably an issue in something not shown.

Comment: ever heard of debug? first try to debug your output variable with cout, then without cout and compare.. I doubt that there will be any change but post the results. And next thing.. you actually can use strings and I think that if we got string named S you can pass as parameter this &S[0] . It's working with vectors so give it a try... good luck

Comment: Do you mean that with the code listed as is, without removing the first `cout`, everything works as expected (both `cout`s work and the file gets removed)? Are tarball() and gzip() library functions or your own?

Comment: @GMan, currently, the C++ standard does not guarantee that `@tarout[0]` works if you want a `char*` pointing to the string. I believe they added a similar guarantee (that vector already provices) in C++0x for std::string. And it probably works anways... but... just saying...

Comment: @sellibitze: It does, actually, but the way in which is does it is "broken" in the standard. `operator[]` is defined in terms of the `data()` function, which returns a non-null-terminated (hence why I say to add it) pointer to "pointer to the initial element of an array whose first size() elements equal the corresponding elements of the string controlled by \*this." Note that *both* the const and non-const overloads of `operator[]` are defined in terms of `data()`, but there is only a const `data()`. The intention was that `operator[]` would cough up an array, but technically the standard...

Comment: ...definition is foo-bar. Like you say, they clarify/fix this in C++0x, every C++03 compiler now implements it correctly, and it was the intention of the C++03 standard. So I don't really see a problem looking past the specification error and saying it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new/malloc do not initialize memory, so I'm fairly certain that you have no NULL terminator at the end of tarout.

I suspect if you run your original code through a debugger or simply print out *(tarout+5), you would see that there is no '0' there.

Given your comments regrading the use of std::string, I would write:

```
const char * file_ext = ".temp";

// no magic numbers...and an obvious + 1 for null terminator
size_t len = strlen(output)+strlen(file_ext)+1;

char *tarout = new char[len];

memset(tarout, 0, len);

strcpy(tarout, output);
strcat(tarout, file_ext);

// If you feel memset is wasteful, you can use
*(tarout+len-1) = 0;

...
```